# Multidimensional Arrays lengths in Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

How to find the lengths of a multidimensional array with non equal indices?

For example, I have `int[][] pathList = new int[6][4]`

Without actually hard-coding the indices, I need to find the '6' and the '4'.

I can find the 6 with `pathList.length`, but how to obtain the '4'?

Comment: The key to understanding the answer to this is in understanding that a multidimensional array is an array-of-arrays, that is, an array where each element is in turn in an array.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

This will give you the length of the array at index `i`

```
pathList[i].length
```

It's important to note that unlike C or C++, the length of the elements of a two-dimensional array in Java need not be equal. For example, when `pathList` is instantiated equal to `new int[6][]`, it can hold 6 `int []` instances, each of which can be a different length.

---

So when you create arrays the way you've shown in your question, you may as well do

```
 pathList[0].length
```

since you know that they all have the same length. In the other cases, you need to define, specific to your application exactly *what* the length of the second dimension means - it might be the maximum of the lengths all the elements, or perhaps the minimum. In most cases, you'll need to iterate over all elements and read their lengths to make a decision:

```
for(int i = 0; i < pathList.length; i++)
{
    int currLen = pathList[i].length;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

This is for a 3 dimensional array.

```
 int x[][][]=new int[5][8][10];
        System.out.println(x.length+" "+x[1].length+" "+x[0][1].length);
```

OUTPUT : 
5 8 10

Comment: I was unsure about the higher dimensions, so I tested it: For a 4th dimensional array:  `System.out.println(x.length+" "+x[1].length+" "+x[0][1].length+" "+x[0][0][1].length);`, hence, to get the length (number of elements) in the `i`'th row of an `n`-dimensional array (with `n>2`), one types: `<arrayname>` followed by the `n-2` of the following characters: `[0]` followed by `[1].length.

Answer (score 7):

Java has "jagged" multidimensional arrays, which means that each "row" in your two-dimensional array can have a different number of components. If you can assume that each row has the same number of components, use:

```
pathList[0].length;
```

Otherwise, you will have to iterate:

```
int maxRowLength = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < pathList.length; i++) {
    if (maxRowLength < pathList[i].length) {
        maxRowLength = pathList[i].length;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For 2 D array :-

```
int x[][] = new int[6][12];
System.out.println(x.length + " " + x[1].length);
```

OUTPUT : 6 12

Answer (score 2):

`pathList.length` gives you the number of rows. This means it will output 6 for `int[6][4]`
`pathList[i].length` gives you the number of columns in the ith row. Since `int[6][4]` can be seen as a rectangle it will always output 4.

Answer (score 1):

In java we can define array of arrays which we call multi dimensional arrays.By array of arrays we mean that a single elment of our array is again an array (in java can be of multiple length).To find length of multi array having all subarray of same size,we can use:

```
int[][]a=new int[3][3];//let a[][] be my array
a.length will work.   //a is an object of proxy class and length is its property.
```

However,if you have subarrays of different sizes then you have to iterate it.

```
for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        int cur_size=a[i].length;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java we can't use Length field like we used to one-dimensional arrays.
So simply writing a few lines of code solves this problem.
First, you need to know that the output of the Length field in multidimensional arrays is the number of rows.I mean when you have below array

int[][] numbers = {{1,2,3,4,2,6},{4,5,6,7}};

the result of
System.out.println(numbers.length);
is 2, because you have 2 rows. So, you should use this to solve this problem.
Example:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Array definition
    int[][] numbers = {{1,2,3,4,2,6},{4,5,6,7}};

    //Number of array's elements
    int result = 0;

    //calculate via loop
    for(int i=0; i< numbers.length; i++){
        result +=  numbers[i].length;
    }

    //output
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can find '4' by using pathlist[i].length

Please rectify me if I am wrong as I am a novice and would help me in understanding Java better. The following code may help you in understanding.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        int num[][] = new int[1][3];
        for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < num[i].length; j++) {
                num[i][j] = 10;
                System.out.println("num [" + i + "] [" + j + "] = " + num[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

3-D array length

```
int[][][] a = new int[2][3][7];
int length=0;
for(int[][] i:a){
    for(int j[]:i){
        length+=j.length;
    }   
}           
System.out.println(length);
```