# How to determine multidimensional array length?

Tags: java

I've created a multidimensional array and populated it:

```
int[][] multiArray = { {1,2,3} , {4,5,6,7} };
```

and if I do the following:

```
System.out.println(multiArray.length);
```

I'll get the value 2, which is the number of columns in this matrix.

But what is the syntax I have to use in order to get **the length** of a certain column?

I know how to address a specific item in order to get it or change it (for example, multiArray[0][2] would let me address value = 3). Just need to know how to address the length of a specific column.

Comment: You want to find the length of a column or row?

Comment: `multiArray[0].length;` ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multidimensional Arrays lengths in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958186/multidimensional-arrays-lengths-in-java)

Comment: Yeah, that's right. Just the length of a specific column.

Comment: What about `multiArray[pos].length` ?

Comment: With `multiArray[0].length` you can get the length of first row. Butif you want length of columns, you would need some work to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `multiArray[i].length` to get the length of the i'th column.

Comment: That will give the length of `i'th` row. not column.

Comment: Actually, this works for me. Maybe I wasn't clear when talking about rows/columns. What I need is the syntax to get the length (i.e. number of elements) in a choosen index, which is what this instruction gives me. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You can get the length of a specific row by invoking `.length` on it.

```
System.out.println(multiArray[i].length);
```