# Java: length of multidimensional arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I'm using Eclipse Luna and i think it's kind of buggy because when i write:

```
int[][][] a = new int[2][3][4];
System.out.println(a.length+" "+a[0].length+" "+a[1].length);
```

Eclipse shows me:

```
2 3 3
```

but if i use:

```
int[][][] a = new int[2][3][4];
System.out.println(a.length+" "+a[0].length+" "+a[0][0].length);
```

Eclipse shows me:

```
2 3 4
```

I don't understand why but because of this reason my whole project doesn't work anymore...

Comment: What do you expect for the lengths of `a[0]` and `a[1]`? Should they be different?

Comment: i used goodle to find out how to find the lengths of multidimensional arrays and they've shown me these technics: a[0].length, a[1].length, a[2].length, ...

Comment: In a 2D array `a[0]` and `a[1]` refer to a row in the array. Typically, they should be the same length. This equally applies to a 3D array (although I would hesitate to call this a "row").

Comment: @TienDoNam : that would be for the case when the rows have different sizes but the way you declared the array, they all have the same size

Comment: Eclipse Luna is not buggy.  Well, actually, it is, but not because of this.  This is the correct behaviour.

Comment: @TienDoNam :You can see the following link:

[multidimensional-arrays-lengths-in-java][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958186/multidimensional-arrays-lengths-in-java?rq=1

Answer (score 5):

These outputs are perfectly correct. You have a 3-dimensional array of length 2 x 3 x 4 so for all valid indexes i, j :

- `a.length` is 2
- `a[i].length` is 3
- `a[i][j].length` is 4

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367218/getting-the-length-of-two-dimensional-array    ... so i just miss unterstood, thank you

Comment: If you look closely the answer of this question, the array is not declared the way you did. The person who answered did not specify the number of columns per row, and then allocated separately the rows with different lengths. That's why he's getting those outputs.